# load data from db knockoutjs + mv3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

attached the file EXAMPLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/brux88/9fzG4/1/

hi, 
I'm starting to use knockoutjs in an asp.net mvc project.

i have a view :

```
 <button  data-bind='click: load'>Load</button>


<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Colli</th>
                    <th>Tara</th>
                    <th>Peso Tara</th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind='foreach: righe'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select  data-bind="
                           value: selectedCli,
                           options:  clienteList,
                           optionsText: function(item) { return item.Rscli + '-' + item.Codcli },
                           optionsCaption: '--Seleziona un Cliente--'"
                           style=" width: 150px">
                        </select>
                     </td>
                    <td >
                        <input data-bind='value: Ncolli' />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="value: selectedTara,
                                          options:  taraList,
                                          optionsText:  function(item) { return item.Destara  + 

'-' + item.Codtara},
                        optionsCaption: '--Seleziona un Cliente--'"

                                style=" width: 150px">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <input  data-bind="value: Ptara" />
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.rimuoviRiga'>Elimina</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button   data-bind='click: aggiungiRiga'>Aggiungi</button>
        <button  data-bind='click: salva'>Salva</button>
        <button  data-bind='click: annulla'>Annulla</button>​
```

my result from data db:

```
[{"Codcli":4,"Rscli":"antonio","Codtart":"1002","Despar":"ciliegino","Ncolli":10,"Pcolli":100,"Codtara":"03","Destara":"","Ptara":82,"Pnetto":18,"Prezzo":1},{"Codcli":1,"Rscli":"bruno","Codtart":"1001","Despar":"pomodoro","Ncolli":10,"Pcolli":100,"Codtara":"03","Destara":"","Ptara":10,"Pnetto":90,"Prezzo":1}]
```

my viewmodel knockoutjs:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
  var listCli= [{Codcli: 1,Rscli: "Bruno"},{Codcli: 2,Rscli: "Pippo"},{Codcli: 3,Rscli: "Giacomo"}];
var listTa= [{Codtara: 01,Destara: "Plastica",Pertara:4},{Codtara: 02,Destara: "Legno",Pertara:6},{Codtara: 03,Destara: "Ploto",Pertara:8}];

var mydataserver = [{"Codcli":3,"Rscli":"Giacomo","Ncolli":10,"Codtara":"03","Destara":"Legno","Ptara":82},{"Codcli":1,"Rscli":"Bruno","Ncolli":10,"Codtara":"02","Destara":"Plastica","Ptara":10}];

 var RigaOrdine = function () {
     var self = this;
                self.selectedCli = ko.observable();
                self.clienteList = ko.observableArray(listCli);            
                self.Ncolli = ko.observable();
                self.selectedTara = ko.observable();
                self.taraList = ko.observableArray(listTa);
                self.Ptara = ko.observable();


                self.Ncolli.subscribe(function () {
                    self.Ptara(self.Ncolli() ? self.selectedTara().Pertara * self.Ncolli() : 0);
                });



                self.selectedTara.subscribe(function () {
                    self.Ptara(self.Ncolli() ? self.selectedTara().Pertara * self.Ncolli() : self.selectedTara().Pertara);
                });
            };


            var Ordine = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.righe = ko.observableArray([new RigaOrdine()]); // Put one line in by default



                // Operations
                self.aggiungiRiga = function () { 
                    self.righe.push(new RigaOrdine());
                        };
                self.rimuoviRiga = function (riga) { 
                    self.righe.remove(riga);
                        };


                self.salva = function() {
                 var righe = $.map(self.righe(), function (riga) {
                        return riga.selectedCli() ? {
                            Codcli: riga.selectedCli().Codcli,
                            Rscli: riga.selectedCli().Rscli,
                            Ncolli: riga.Ncolli(),
                            Codtara: riga.selectedTara().Codtara,
                            Ptara: riga.Ptara(),
                            } : undefined;
                    });
                    alert( ko.toJSON(righe));
                    //save to server
                   /* $.ajax({
                        url: "/echo/json/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ko.toJSON(righe),
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data) {
                        }
                    });*/
                    self.righe([new RigaOrdine()]);
                };

                //load from server
                self.load = function() {
                    $.ajax({ url: '/echo/json/', 
                      accepts: "application/json", 

                      cache: false, 
                      statusCode: { 

                        200: function (data) {
                            alert(ko.toJSON(mydataserver));
                            //i do not know apply to viewmodel
                        }, 
                        401: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                          alert('401: Unauthenticated'); 
                         // self.location = "../../Account/Login.html?returnURL=/Index.html"; 
                        } 
                      } 
                    }); 


                };
                self.annulla = function() {
                    self.righe([new RigaOrdine()]);
                };



            };
            var viewmodel = new Ordine();
           ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);


​

    </script>
```

if I want to load data from a db, how do I? Whereas there are dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit weak so I will give you a more general answer.

To answer your question regarding how to load data from a db, it looks like that you have started on the right track. Usually you use an AJAX request to do the async request of data. To do this, knockoutJS provides the following function:

```
$.getJSON("/some/url", function(data) { 
    // Now use this data to update your view models, 
    // and Knockout will update your UI automatically
})
```

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

In the callback provided you will have access to the data returned from the server. It depends on the logic of your application what you want to do here - for some applications it might make sence to update the state of the viewmodel to make corresponding updates in the view.

If your question is more specific, please elaborate. Otherwise, I hope I got you on the right track.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I can retrieve data from the server (see mydataserver) but I can not once update the view with the data received

Comment: Okay :) Which array do you want to populate the data to? And which type of model do your data represent?

Comment: my arrray i want popolute is : cliente and my viewmodel is Ordine()

Answer (score 0):

As i can see.. you may want some good pratice to load.
I'll share with you mine.

Well.. return a Json as an JsonResult.

```
    // POST: /Client/LoadClient
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadClient(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) return null;

        var client = _business.FindById((int) id);

        return Json(
            new
            {
                id = cliente.id,
                name = cliente.name,
                list = cliente.listOfSomething.Select(s => new {idItemFromList = s.idWhatever, nameItemFromList = s.nameWhatever})
            });

    }
```

JS

```
viewmodel.Client.prototype.LoadClient= function (id) {
var self = this;

if (id == 0) {
    return null;
}

$.ajax({
    url: actionURL("LoadClient", "Client"),
    data: { id: parseInt(id) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null)
            self.Load(result);
    }
});
```

Load method.

```
viewmodel.Client.prototype.Load = function (result) {
var self = this;

self.idClient(result.id);
self.nameCliente(result.name);
self.ListOfSomething(result.list);
};
```

and..

ko.applyBinding(*yourModel*);

as u can see I'm using *prototype* it's a good practice too.